# Optimal implementation of a bijective mapping on a large scale

Tags: python, data-structures

Here's an interesting problem: given a large amount of text data (~5 GB of words as strings), I need to build a mapping such that every word is associated with a unique integer. It should be noted that it needs to work the other way - every integer should also be associated with a unique word (hence why its a bijective mapping).

I also need to be able to quickly look up a word by its associated number.

The following is the most naive implementation I can think of:

```
   data_structure = []
   for word in giant_list_of_words:
      if (word not in data_structure):
         data_structure.append(word)
   return data_structure

   def lookup(data_structure, i):
       return data_structure[i]
```

With this approach, the mapping is simply words to their index in the list. Building the mapping is slow, but lookup is fast.

Here's another approach:

```
def mapping():
   data_structure = {}
   count = 0
   for word in giant_list_of_words:
      if (word not in data_structure):
         data_structure[word] = count
         count += 1
   return data_structure

def lookup(data_structure, i):
   retval = ''
   for key in data_structure:
      if (data_structure[key] == i):
          retval = key
          break
   return retval
```

This gets built fast, but is slow to index. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you need lookups going both ways, could you just build two dictionaries? Or rather, since the numbers you're associating with words are integers in the sequence 0,1,2,3,... the other lookup could be a list instead of a dictionary. Does this take too much memory?

Comment: Probably, since it would basically be two copies of the entire dataset loaded in memory

Comment: It wouldn't be two copies of each string - just two pointers to each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's rare that there is an absolutely optimal way to solve a data-structure design problem in Python, but for this question there is a good candidate.

Each and every distinct object in Python, including strings, has a number `id(obj)` which is unique, and never changes for the lifetime of the object.

It happens that the `_ctypes` module has a function named `PyObj_FromPtr` which looks up an object by its `id`:

```py
>>> word = 'supercalifragilisticexpialadocious'
>>> word_id = id(word)
>>> word_id
139817888649440
>>> from _ctypes import PyObj_FromPtr
>>> PyObj_FromPtr(word_id)
'supercalifragilisticexpialadocious'
```

This is all built into the language - Python assigns these ids to your objects whether you need them or not, and the lookup is fast because (as a CPython implementation detail) the id of an object is its memory address. So it's hard to imagine there is any more efficient solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

## OPTION (1)

If your strings have the following properties:

- strings are not case-sensitive. `"ApPle"` == `"APPLE"` == `"apple"`
- only use the characters `0-9` and `a-z`
- No `'/\:;,.!@#$%^&*(){}[]+-"`

Then, you could convert the strings into integers using base 36 notation.

```
hash_val = int("apple", base=36)
```

---

## OPTION (2)

Note that python strings have a built-in `hash` function:

```
words = [
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "apple"
    "apple",
    "kiwi",
    "honeydew",
    "kiwi",
]
d = dict()
d_inv = dict()
for word in words:
    hval = hash(word)
    d[word] = hash(word)
    d_inv[hval] = word

print(
    "\n".join(
        str(key).ljust(20) + str(val) for key, val in d.items()
    )
)
```

However, the hash value only stays constant while the program is running. It changes every time you close your program. You would have to save them to file or something. On one run, `hash("apple")` is `1406220762` and the next run it is `1187353108`

Comment: Option 2 will not work, because two different strings can have the same `hash`.